# Internet Explorer 8: Navigate to users home page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've been using the following script for a few years now to navigate to the users home page when a button is clicked. However, with the start of IE8, this does not work as it appears "about:home" is no longer valid.

```
if(window.home) {
  // for everything but IE:
  window.home();
} else {
  // for IE:
  window.location = "about:home"; // IE8 will error here if the location is "about:home"
}
```

Is there a new way of getting Internet Explorer 8+ to navigate to the users home page? The script must be cross browser.

Comment: interesting question... although I've never fully understood why one would want to add this... as the user can click Home or press ALT+Home whenever they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, though the resolution seems very strange to me:

1. Create a new CSS element:
   .hpClass { behavior:url(#default#homepage) }
2. Create a span referencing the new CSS & creating a class name:
   `<span id="hp" class="hpClass"></span>`
3. Wrap it all up checking the IE version and using the new object or the old "about:home" style:

   `if(window.home) {
     window.home();
   } else {
     ieVer = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
     if(ieVer <= 7) {
       window.location = "about:home";
     } else {
       hp.navigateHomePage();
     }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

The URI to be navigated to when `about:home` is entered in the location bar is stored in the Registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs
```

However, this feature seems to be disabled for IE8. The entry `Home` is a REG_DWORD and not a string value containing the URL of the home page. This might be related to the feature of having several home pages that can be opened in tabs.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on the meaning of the `Home` REG_DWORD value though but it is possible to change it to a string value. Then `about:home` will navigate to the URL specified in that value. However, this is most likely not a solution for you as this requires admin permissions for the registry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we have to use DHTML Behaviors of Internet Explorer... I haven't found any pure JavaScript solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                                        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:ie>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Home Link - Test</title>
  <style>
  @media all {
    IE\:HOMEPAGE {behavior:url(#default#homepage)}
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function goHome() {                                   // Firefox
    if (window.home) {
      window.home();
    }
    else {                                              // IE
      if (navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1] <= 7) { // IE 4-7
        window.location = "about:home";
      }
      else {                                            // IE 8
        oHomePage.navigateHomePage();
        event.returnValue = false;
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ie:homepage id="oHomePage" />
  <a href="#" onclick="goHome();">Home</a>
  <!-- <input type="button" value="Navigate" onclick="fnGo()"/> -->
</body>
</html>
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms531398(en-us,VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms531079(v=VS.85).aspx